# Error creating bean with name 'myServiceCustomerOffer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf

I have defined my `bean.xml` as below for Web Service

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="serviceCustomerOffer" implementor="#myServiceCustomerOffer"
        implementorClass="com.abc.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOfferImpl"
        address="/getCustomerOffer" />

    <bean id="myServiceCustomerOffer" name="myServiceCustomerOfferName" class="com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOfferImpl" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="CustomerOfferFacade" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CustomerOfferFacade" name="CustomerOfferFacade"
        class="com.abc.mime.ws.facade.customeroffer.CustomerOfferFacadeImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="customerOfferDAO" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="generalDomainSql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerOfferDAO" name="customerOfferDAOName"
        class="com.abc.mime.ws.dao.bscs.sql.customeroffer.CustomerOfferDAOImpl">

    </bean>
          <bean id="generalDomainSql" name="generalDomainSqlName"
        class="com.abcd.mime.ws.dao.bscs.sql.generaldomain.GeneralDomainDAOImpl">
    </bean>
```

I am getting following error while deployment on tomcat 6 server. all the classes are defined in proper structure.

```
13/Feb/2014 05:08:10,423 [http-8090-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCustomerOffer': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myServiceCustomerOffer' while setting constructor argument with index 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceCustomerOffer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'myServiceCustomerOffer' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceCustomerOffer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'myServiceCustomerOffer' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
```

Here is `ManageCustomerOfferImpl.java` which is used in my code. This is also mapped in wsdl file.

```
package com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOffer;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOffer")
public class ManageCustomerOfferImpl implements ManageCustomerOffer{



        private CustomerOfferFacade customerOfferFacade; 

        private Log logger = LogFactory
                .getLog(com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOfferImpl.class);

public ManageCustomerOfferImpl( CustomerOfferFacade _customerOffer) { this.customerOfferFacade = _customerOffer; }

        @Override
        public CustomerOfferResponse getCustomerOffer(CustomerOfferRequest customerOfferRequest) throws CustomerOfferFault {

            logger.debug("ManageCustomerOfferImpl - getCustomerOffer: Received from Consumer MSISDN = ["+ customerOfferRequest.getMSISDN()+"]");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ustomerOfferResponse customerOfferResponse = customerOfferFacade.getCustomerOffer(customerOfferRequest);


            logger.debug("ManageCustomerOfferImpl - getCustomerOffer: Sending Response back to Consumer =>>  "+ customerOfferResponse);
            return customerOfferResponse;
        }

    }
```

It was working earlier but while making some corrections it stopped working

```
Error13/Feb/2014 09:22:06,625 [http-8090-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCustomerOffer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
Caused by: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ref.SoftReference.get(SoftReference.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2285)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
    Feb 13, 2014 9:22:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCustomerOffer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ref.SoftReference.get(SoftReference.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2285)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:301)
```

Comment: I mean the error is pretty obvious. Can we see your `ManageCustomerOfferImpl` class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added the code for `ManageCustomerOfferImpl.java`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated the code of `ManageCustomerOfferImpl.java`

Comment: Post the full stack trace as well. Seems like you have a recursive loop.

Comment: updated the error above .. removed some repeated traces

Comment: Can you update your code? What is the field `getCustomerOffer` in the constructor? Are you recursively calling the same method? That will end up in an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: I have update the statement and updated it ... still gettting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your bean is declared as

```
<bean id="myServiceCustomerOffer" name="myServiceCustomerOfferName" class="com.abcd.mime.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageCustomerOfferImpl" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="CustomerOfferFacade" />
</bean>
```

That means it will use a constructor that expects an argument of whatever type the `CustomerOfferFacade` is. However, your class doesn't have such a constructor. It therefore fails.

I don't know what `CustomerOfferFacadeImpl` is so I don't know what you're expecting to do with it, but you'll need to add a constructor with a parameter of that type if you want your `<bean>` declaration to work.

Comment: @RaG Ok. Then what? Also, don't put code in comments.

Comment: ERROR:
`13/Feb/2014 08:36:25,090 [http-8090-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCustomerOffer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
Caused by: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.System$2.getConstantPool(System.java:1130)
 at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1014)
 at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:1000)
`